# Cost categories of a software organization

Tags: budget, software, start-up

I am a lead software engineer that has been asked to become part of a small pre-seed-level software startup. One of the principals has asked me to come up with a 1-, 3- and 5-year *estimate* operating budget for a small development team (which would include myself).

I am comfortable doing my own research so long as I know all the different categories + classifications of typical software startup costs. The major categories I can think of are:

- Labor

  - FT Employee
  - Contractor
- Tools (IDEs, software licenses, etc.)
- Services (3rd party SaaS)
- Infrastructure (servers, SSL certs, etc.)
- Audits

  - Cyber-security
  - SOC2, business compliance, etc.

Please note that I'm not asking for a list of typical *business* cost categories, only those that would pertain to the development & maintenance of software in a typical engineering organization (the idea is that I would become the Engineering Manager/Director for the team and hence in control of the engineering budget).

**Are there any other major categories of costs that anyone can think of?**

Comment: it's impossible to run a software startup for less than $0.5m a year.  that is the bare minimum.  nothing is more expensive than programmers.

Comment: If the guy actually wants you to quote stuff like tools, your Firebase monthly bill etc, that is quite naive.  Just put all that down as 5000 a month.  The absolutely overwhelming cost is programmers.  Determining the cost of a startup, means, determining how many programmers you need.  Sure, at the end just add a small amount for a few laptops, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just things I've thought of:

Equipment - Computers themselves (which need changing every 2 years), maybe phones, headsets, comfy chairs etc

Legal - Pat testing for instance (depends on where you are from though I guess)

Remote communication - Probably falls under tools,
 (GoToMyPC, team viewer etc..)

Also make them aware that testers and technical support will be needed as well, although depends what project you are doing.

Recruitment - Hiring through agencys costs about 10% of the coders annual salary.

Tea, Biscuits and an unlimited supply of coffee :-)

Comment: "Hiring through agencys costs about 10% " indeed it is often far more than that.